# How to add `--health-cmd='mysqladmin ping --silent'` and `--health-interval='1s'` options to dockerode's createContainer() function?

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to use node.js to manipulate docker containers. And I found a module called [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode), which seems like the tool I need.

However, I haven't found any way to add `--health-cmd` and `--health-interval` options to `createContainer` function.

These 2 options are used in `docker run` command. You can find them by `docker run --help | grep health`:

> --health-cmd string              Command to run to check health
>   --health-interval duration       Time between running the check (ms|s|m|h) (default 0s)

I've tried the following code, but the 2 options don't work inside the code.

```
const Docker = require('dockerode')
const docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'})

docker.createContainer({
Image: 'mysql:5.7',
name: 'myContainer',
env: ['MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword'],
'health-cmd': 'mysqladmin ping --silent',
'health-interval': '1s',
HostConfig: {
    PortBindings: {
    '3306/tcp': [
        {
        HostPort: '3306'
        }
    ]
    }
}
}, (err, container) => {
if (err) {
    console.error(`create err:${err}`)
} else {
    container.start((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(`start err: ${err}`)
    } else {
        console.log(`data: ${data}`)
    }
    })
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948747/how-to-get-started-with-dockerode). I have found the [document of Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/) and figured out the correct way to add the 2 options:

```
const Docker = require('dockerode')
const docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'})

docker.createContainer({
  Image: 'mysql:5.7',
  name: 'myContainer',
  env: ['MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword'],
  Healthcheck: {
    Test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'mysqladmin ping'],
    Interval: 1000000000
  },
  HostConfig: {
    PortBindings: {
      '3306/tcp': [
        {
          HostPort: '3306'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}, (err, container) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`create err:${err}`)
  } else {
    container.start((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`start err: ${err}`)
      } else {
        console.log(`data: ${data}`)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

You can find that `createContainer` calls `POST /containers/create` from the source code located in `node_modules/dockerode/lib/docker.js`.